# Randomly select n items from a map

Tags: java, list, random, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to randomly generate 'n' number of items from a HashMap where 'n' is determined by the user.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String []args){
    int numColors = 3;
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("White","FFFFFF");
    map.put("Blank","000000");
    map.put("Red","ED0A15");
    map.put("Green","06F76C");
    map.put("Blue","0689FF");
    map.put("Sky Blue","00C2FC");
    map.put("Light Blue","08F0FC");
    map.put("Silver","C0BFC5");
    map.put("Mint","ABD3CA");
    map.put("Off White","FFEFF0");
    map.put("Purple","736FFA");
    map.put("Lavendar","DEBEEF");
    map.put("Hot Pink","F5159A");
    map.put("Pink","DB39CC");
    map.put("Light Pink","F5C2E3");
    map.put("Blush","C95FA7");
    map.put("Orange","D4361B");
    map.put("Yellow","DEF231");
    map.put("Warm White","F3E4C3");
    map.put("Turquoise","01DCA4");

    List<String> valuesList = new ArrayList<String>(map.values());
    int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(valuesList.size());
    String randomValue = valuesList.get(randomIndex);

    System.out.printf(randomValue);
}
```

It prints 1 random color for me (in hex) which I want, however I am unsure of how/which loop to use in order to generate say 3 random hex colors from the map. I declared numColors as 3 just to try and test this out.

Here is what I ended up going with:

```
public static void main(String []args){
    int numColors = 3;
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("White","FFFFFF");
    map.put("Blank","000000");
    map.put("Red","ED0A15");
    map.put("Green","06F76C");
    map.put("Blue","0689FF");
    map.put("Sky Blue","00C2FC");
    map.put("Light Blue","08F0FC");
    map.put("Silver","C0BFC5");
    map.put("Mint","ABD3CA");
    map.put("Off White","FFEFF0");
    map.put("Purple","736FFA");
    map.put("Lavendar","DEBEEF");
    map.put("Hot Pink","F5159A");
    map.put("Pink","DB39CC");
    map.put("Light Pink","F5C2E3");
    map.put("Blush","C95FA7");
    map.put("Orange","D4361B");
    map.put("Yellow","DEF231");
    map.put("Warm White","F3E4C3");
    map.put("Turquoise","01DCA4");

    List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < numColors; i++) {
        String key = keys.get(rand.nextInt(keys.size()));
        System.out.println(map.get(key));
        }

 }
```

Comment: How about you try a for-loop.

Comment: Make a single instance of `Random`, and then use a for loop to run the random selection multiple times.

Comment: would you like duplication??

Comment: I want 3 random colors, so it could duplicate, it might not.

Comment: @user3130128 for statement is what you need

Comment: I am having trouble trying to comprehend how the syntax would be. As a for-loop is setup like for ( {initialization}; {exit condition}; {incrementor} ) code_block;

Comment: You basically want to select a random subset of `map.values()`. So the answer should be covered over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136474/best-way-to-pick-a-random-subset-from-a-collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you could do it with

```
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < numColors; i++) {
    String key = keys.get(rand.nextInt(keys.size()));
    System.out.println(map.get(key));
}
```

Comment: Thank you Elliott that worked perfectly. Just a side question, this solution allows for duplicate colors correct? So FFFFFF could show up twice theoretically.

Comment: Answered my own question, it does allow duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to shuffle the entire map using `Collections.shuffle(map)`. Then just iterating over it and picking the first *n* elements.

Of course this doesn't make sense if the map is huge and you only need a couple of elements.

Edit:

Naturally, with this solution you won't get any duplicate entries

Comment: In my code example, that is all the map elements so it is not very large.

Comment: It'd probably be good to note that this prevents duplicate results.

Answer (score 0):

Changes are mentioned in comments

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numColors = 3;
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("White", "FFFFFF");
        map.put("Blank", "000000");
        map.put("Red", "ED0A15");
        map.put("Green", "06F76C");
        map.put("Blue", "0689FF");
        map.put("Sky Blue", "00C2FC");
        map.put("Light Blue", "08F0FC");
        map.put("Silver", "C0BFC5");
        map.put("Mint", "ABD3CA");
        map.put("Off White", "FFEFF0");
        map.put("Purple", "736FFA");
        map.put("Lavendar", "DEBEEF");
        map.put("Hot Pink", "F5159A");
        map.put("Pink", "DB39CC");
        map.put("Light Pink", "F5C2E3");
        map.put("Blush", "C95FA7");
        map.put("Orange", "D4361B");
        map.put("Yellow", "DEF231");
        map.put("Warm White", "F3E4C3");
        map.put("Turquoise", "01DCA4");

        // scanner for accepting values
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number");
        int N = scan.nextInt();

        // random object for generating random values
        Random rand = new Random();

        // converting map values to list
        List<String> valuesList = new ArrayList<String>(map.values());

        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            // choose random value
            int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(valuesList.size());
            // get value
            String randomValue = valuesList.get(randomIndex);
            // printing
            System.out.println("Random value " + i + " : " + randomValue);
        }
    }
}
```

To prevent duplicates you can do something like this :

```
// random object for generating random values
Random rand = new Random();

// converting map values to list
List<String> valuesList = new ArrayList<String>(map.values());

Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

while (set.size() != N) {
    int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(valuesList.size());
    String randomValue = valuesList.get(randomIndex);
    set.add(randomValue);
}

System.out.println(set);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Malt suggested, to prevent duplicates and keep code clean:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList(map.values() );
Collections.shuffle(list);
```