# Display a random set of characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, random

I am building a game with asp, sql, c#, and XML.
I have an xml document that holds all the characters and their numbers (which is used to display their pictures).

I am pulling the information and displaying it using a DataList.
Currently it pulls and displays all the characters in my xml. I desire for it only to pull a certain amount of characters (generated randomly) and display those for the duration of the game. Then the next game a different set of characters will be randomly chosen and played with.

Not sure if it's important to note. The game is a two player turn based game. The set of characters displayed needs to be the same for both players.

Comment: It sounds like you want to choose a random subset of elements from a larger collection. See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/48087/1127114) for possible approaches.

Comment: You have a list of N items, and you want a random selection of K of them.  You can use a [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to shuffle the list, then take the first K items.  This guarantees no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Picking x random items from a set list is something you can do with a [shuffle bag](http://www.dotnetperls.com/shuffle).