# how to get random amount of details from a list or var in c#

Tags: c#, list, random, var

I'm reading result from an json file inside the local project.it returns more than 4000 result.I want to get only random number of results (between 500- 1000) from that result.

```
 var finalResultz = finalResults("All","All","All");//step one
```

in here it returns more than 4000 results.then I put into a list like this.

```
List<Results> searchOne = new List<Results>();//step two
foreach(var itms in finalResultz)
{
    searchOne.Add(new Results 
    {
        resultDestination = returnRegionName(itms.areaDestination),
        mainImageurl = itms.testingImageUrl
     });
 }
    
 ViewBag.requested = searchOne;
```

but I want to get only the results like I said.I want to resize the count in step one or in step two.how can I do that.hope your help.

Comment: What do you exactly mean on random number of results between 500-1000? You need first N results, a distributed with step 2,3,4... ?

Comment: yes, that is what I want exactly,random number of results between 500-1000

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select a random N elements from List<T> in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48087/select-a-random-n-elements-from-listt-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Be sure to mark the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Random`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx) class and [`Take()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx) method to extract N elements.

```
// create new instance of random class
Random rnd = new Random(); 

// get number of elements that will be retrieved from 500 to 1000
var elementsCount = rnd.Next(500, 1000);

// order source collection by random numbers and then take N elements: 
var searchOne = finalResultz.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).Take(elementsCount);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want a random count of results, you can just `.Take()` a random number of the records.  First, you'll need a `Random`:

```
var random = new Random();
```

If you want between 500-1000, just get a random value in that range:

```
var count = random.Next(500, 1001);
```

Then you can take those records from the collection:

```
var newList = oldList.Take(count).ToList();
```

(Of course, you may want to make sure it *contains* that many records first.)

Note that this will take the *first* N records from the collection.  So in order to take random records from *anywhere* in the collection, you'd need to shuffle (randomize) the collection before taking the records.  There are a number of ways you can do that.  One approach which may not be the absolute fastest but is generally "fast enough" for simplicity is to just sort by a GUID.  So something like this:

```
var newList = oldList.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(count).ToList();
```

Or maybe use the randomizer again:

```
var newList = oldList.OrderBy(x => random.Next()).Take(count).ToList();
```

Comment: thanx for your answer