# Simple Program Taking Extremely Long Time To Finish

Tags: c#

i am trying to create minesweeper in c# to do this i create an multidimensional array and then randomly pick positions using

```
Random rand = new Random;
```

the problem comes when trying to run the code, when i run it it takes an extremely long time to finish, i suspect it is because of the while loop and the if statements, if the `rand.Next` keeps getting the same values it could cause the loop to run for a long time. is there something im doing that is afftecting the pseudo randomness of my numbers. code below.

after returning to this questing a while later in an attempt to make it less horrendous it is clear that the reason for the program taking so long to run lies within the

```
while (counter < numberOfMines)
    {
        if (Minefield[randomNumber1, randomNumber2] == 9)
        {
            counter--;
        }
        else
        {
            Minefield[randomNumber1, randomNumber2] = 9;
            counter++;
        }
        randomNumber1 = (rand.Next(4)) + 1;
        randomNumber2 = (rand.Next(4)) + 1;
    }
```

section of the code. The reason that it was taking so long is that i was treating the while loop like a for loop and taking away from the counter when it was failing to place a mine. this is incorrect and i should have just not added to it.

```
using System;

class MainClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int boardSize = 5;
        int numberOfMines = 25;
        GenerateMinefield(boardSize,numberOfMines);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static int[,] GenerateMinefield(int boardSize, int numberOfMines)
    {
        int[,] Minefield = new int[boardSize + 2, boardSize + 2];
        for (int i = 0; i <= boardSize; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= boardSize; j++)
            {
                Minefield[j, i] = 0;
            }
        }

        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNumber1 = (rand.Next(4)) + 1;
        int randomNumber2 = (rand.Next(4)) + 1;
        int counter = 0;
        while (counter < numberOfMines)
        {
            if (Minefield[randomNumber1, randomNumber2] == 9)
            {
                counter--;
            }
            else
            {
                Minefield[randomNumber1, randomNumber2] = 9;
                counter++;
            }
            randomNumber1 = (rand.Next(4)) + 1;
            randomNumber2 = (rand.Next(4)) + 1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= boardSize; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= boardSize; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(Minefield[j, i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(Minefield[boardSize, i]);
        }
        
        return Minefield;
    }
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you learn to use Visual Studio's built-in debugger. Pay close attention to the value `counter` has as your loop progresses.

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve with the `while` loop?

Comment: In addition to VS debugger, you can add some logging and use [Stopwatch Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1) to gage what's taking so long. Debug or output some diagnostics into a log file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your problem is in the `counter--`. You're not removing a mine, you're simply failing to place a mine, so `counter` should be unchanged.

Comment: ah you're not wrong, i got confused as i was previously doing the same thing with a for loop in which case i would have to minus one away, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly the `while` loop should look something like this:

```
        while (counter < numberOfMines)
        {
            if (Minefield[randomNumber1, randomNumber2] != 9)
            {
                  Minefield[randomNumber1, randomNumber2] = 9;
                  counter++;
            }
            randomNumber1 = (rand.Next(4)) + 1;
            randomNumber2 = (rand.Next(4)) + 1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to do the following:

1. Create a minefield board of size (N+2, N+2)
2. Fill the interior of the board (excluding the cells on the border) randomly with a specified number of mines.

It's possible to do this in linear time (i.e. O(N)) as follows:

1. Create a 1D array of bools with the same number of elements as the interior of the minefield, excluding the border cells.
2. Fill the start of array with a number of `true` values equal to the number of mines that you want.
3. Shuffle the array - now the "mines" are in random locations.
4. Go through the array and for every `true` value set the corresponding value in the minefield to 9.

It's slightly inefficient to create a temporary array almost the same size as the minefield, but this has the advantage that it will always run in linear time.

Putting this together:

```
static int[,] GenerateMinefield(int boardSize, int numberOfMines, Random rng)
{
    if (numberOfMines > boardSize)
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(numberOfMines)} exceeds {nameof(boardSize)}");

    int[,] minefield = new int[boardSize + 2, boardSize + 2]; // Already filled with zeros.
    bool[] mines     = new bool[(boardSize-2)*2];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMines; ++i) // Set the first 'numberOfMines' to 9.
        mines[i] = true;

    Shuffle(mines, rng); // Now the mines are in random locations.

    for (int i = 1, n = 0; i < boardSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < boardSize; j++, n++)
        {
            if (mines[n])
                minefield[j, i] = 9;
        }
    }

    return minefield;
}

static void Shuffle<T>(IList<T> array, Random rng)
{
    for (int n = array.Count; n > 1;)
    {
        int k = rng.Next(n);
        --n;
        T temp = array[n];
        array[n] = array[k];
        array[k] = temp;
    }
}
```

(That's using a standard shuffle algorithm.)

There's a better but more subtle way of doing this that doesn't require a separate array of bools. You can use the following code:

```
static int[,] GenerateMinefield(int boardSize, int numberOfMines, Random rng)
{
    if (numberOfMines > boardSize)
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(numberOfMines)} exceeds {nameof(boardSize)}");

    int[,] minefield = new int[boardSize + 2, boardSize + 2]; // Already filled with zeros.
    int available = boardSize*2;

    for (int i = 1, n = 0; i < boardSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < boardSize; j++, n++)
        {
            if (rng.NextDouble() < numberOfMines / (double)available)
            {
                minefield[j, i] = 9;
                --numberOfMines;
            }
        }
    }

    return minefield;
}
```

The drawback of this approach is that it is not obvious how it works! It's also not *completely* evenly distributed, but I suspect that wouldn't matter for this program. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48089/106159) for further discussion.